# Ubuntu 23.04 - do I need to manually install OpenCL drivers?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel, gpu, gpu-driver

I bought a laptop (https://www.dell.com/de-de/shop/dell-notebooks/xps-15-laptop/spd/xps-15-9530-laptop) that shipped with Windows, and I installed Ubuntu 23.04 in a dual-boot setting. I could not use an older version.

The GPU (Intel A370M) is listed via `lshw`, and `clinfo` yields

```
Number of platforms                               0

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.3.1
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0
```

However, an application for molecular dynamics (OpenMM) is unable to find my OpenCL.
Is it possible that this is due to lacking drivers, or should I be fine given the fact that both the GPU and OpenCL is seen by the OS?
On the Intel website, there is only a driver listed for Ubuntu 22.04.

Edit: Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```bash
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (RPL-P)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

edit 2: According to the comments the question is whether I need to install new OpenCL drivers (not GPU drivers), so I modified the question title.

Comment: Post output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` terminal command

Comment: "On the Intel website, there is only a driver listed for Ubuntu 22.04."  you can use all drivers from the current LTS and newer versions

Comment: @Rinzwind, thank you, I did not know. Then the only question is whether I have to install/update my drivers.

Comment: I think you should rename "GPU Drivers" to "OpenCL Drivers" in topic name

Comment: Your usual (not considering OpenCL) GPU driver works fine